# Template parsing error: template: :1: unclosed action

Tags: docker

While doing the Network Container lesson [Network Containers Lesson](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/networkingcontainers/) I ran into an error

```
Template parsing error: template: :1: unclosed action
```

when executing

```
docker inspect --format='{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks}}'  db
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: What is your environment?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I'm running the commands on Windows 10 and the strings must be enclosed with double quotes. Therefore, rewriting the command as

```
docker inspect --format="{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks}}"  db
```

solved it.